# How do you name these tags in CSS?

Tags: html, css

My code is too big, and I'm getting very confused!

I need to know how to name, in my CSS file, a DIV with UL and LI, but naming the ID's.

For example:

**THE HTML**

```
<div id="expl">  
  <ul id="yes">   
    <li id="no">   
    </li>  
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Is the way I am naming it in the CSS correct? I want to edit `#exp1 ul li`, but naming the IDs.

**THE CSS**

```
#exp1 #yes #no{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Newbie over here! Thanks!

Comment: 1) right click element 2) inspect element 3) ? 4) profit!

Comment: You could have just tried this yourself, and found your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is one of many valid ways of selecting the `<li>` tag. You could also simply use `#no`, since IDs are unique within the document, unless you specifically need to apply styles to only `#no` contained within `#exp1 #yes`.

Comment: Thanks buddy ;). 3 hours to do a damn slider... but now I know haha

Answer (score 0):

```
#exp1, #yes, #no{...}
```

Auto

```
margin:0 auto;
padding:0 auto;
```

Margin

```
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

Simple

```
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
```